# Adding The Post Template Dropdown to WP-Admin

Tags: posts, customization, templates

I'm developing a WP theme from the ground up for the first time. Having build WP sites before, I know there to be an option in Posts that will allow for the selection of a specific template.

I have created the custom Post Templates with the appropriate headers, but the option to select anything is simply not there in WP Admin.

Do I need to add something in functions.php in order for this to show?

I've searched high and low for an answer but no-one seems to be having this issue and simply recommend disabling and enabling the theme, which has no affect.

Thanks in advance!

Template Code:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name Posts: Rooms Template
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

            <div class="col-md-4">

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-8">

                <?php if (have_posts()) :?><?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

                    <p><?php the_content();?></p>   

                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>

            </div>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Please post the code for the template. It is hard to say where the problem is without seeing the code

Comment: By default, only pages support templates. If you want the same for posts, try [Custom Post Template](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-template/)

Comment: Thanks @TheDeadMedic this does work.

It would be nice to know how this should function without the need for 3rd party plugins though.